# C++ How to pass serveral paramters to a thread? [HANDLE hThread]

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

```
HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ManageThread, (LPVOID)lParam, 0, NULL);
WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
```

How can I pass serveral HANDLE param via lParam?

I have to use serveral HANDLE variable on hThread.

```
DWORD WINAPI ManageThread(LPVOID lParam)
{
    HANDLE hPingpong = ...; //From lParam;
    HANDLE hVolley = ...; //From lParam;
    ...
    HANDLE hBasket = ...; //From lParam;
    ...

    return GetLastError();
}
```

I would appreciate it if you could help me generate lParam.

Comment: Use a structure or an array. Note that [WaitForMultipleObjects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025(v=vs.85).aspx) requires an array of handles, if you ever plan on using it.

Comment: Dear rcgldr, Can you explain it in detail? I have to pass serveral parameters via only one thread function.

Comment: As an example of using an array, say you create an array of handles named aHandle. Then for each handle, use a define: | #define hPingpong aHandle[0] | #define hVolley aHandle[1] | ... . Set lParam = aHandle when creating the thread.

Comment: Sorry, you didn't understand my question. If that case I cannot use serveral parameter at same time. I had misunderstood before it, but now you explained me wrong way. I can not do what you say. Thank you for your kindness rcgldr.

Comment: Create an array, and pass it via `lParam`.

Comment: I found a way to send several parameters. Make structure contains several types of parameters. Thank you David Heffernan.

Comment: Downvoted. Reason: Lack of research. This question has been asked a bazillion times already, and has been sufficiently answered. Pick a duplicate you like.

Answer (score 0):

I found the best way to pass serveral paramters to single thread.

Using Structure : )

```
structure PARAM_PAIR {
    HANDLE hVolley;
    HANDLE hSoccer;
    ...
    DWORD dwVolleyScore;
    DWORD dwSoccerSocre;
}

PARAM_PAIR* param_pair;
param_pair = new PARAM_PAIR;

HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ManageThread, param_pair, 0, NULL);
WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
```

Thank you for all answered. Bryant